# how to use 1 master(page or model.Model) for many catigories(page)?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I want to get something like this:

[image]
but I have no idea how to do it in wagtail(1 child cant have more then 1 parent), how 2 fix it? I don't want to have 3 master pages in admin panel.

well, I'm newbie in Wagtail, I know about snippets, but I need master page. I know how to do it in Django, but have no idea when using Wagtail.

```
class Master(Page):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contacts = RichTextField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    image = models.ForeignKey('wagtailimages.Image',
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name='+',
                              verbose_name=)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('contacts'),
        FieldPanel('image'),
    ]
```

```
class ProductsIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('intro', classname="full"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            InlinePanel('products_sell', label="Product")],
            heading="Products",),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            InlinePanel('training', label="Training")],
            heading="Training", ),

    ]
```

```
class Training(AbstractProducts):
    product = ParentalKey(
        'ProductsIndexPage',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='training'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

What do the lines in your diagram represent? Are they the class inheritance or the navigation tree?  In other words, how is the master page related to products, training and timetable?

I think rather than diving into the code, it would help to describe what you want your site to do. For example is this a site for a business and you need to have a page that lists all your products, with links to the product details?

You don't need pages to have a relationship at the model level in order to display their content. In [this section of the Wagtail tutorial](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#overriding-context) it shows how to display the most recent blog posts on the BlogIndexPage. That example uses `get_children` because the BlogIndexPage happens to be the parent of all the BlogPages. But there is no reason you can't do some other sort of query in `get_context`. For example you could query for 'all product pages tagged "new"' or 'training related to this product'.

If you can step back and give us a better **what you want to do**, then we can better advise you on **how** to do it.

Comment: On the site tree diagram, there are 3 types of products, and all of them have their own master (several may have one master at once). In normal django, I would just write 1 view with a post method, and call it. But I don't understand how to implement it in wagtail. Creating 3 identical pages in the admin panel seems redundant to me.

Comment: Wagtail uses django-treebeard to manage parent/child relationships between pages. This means you are creating a tree so each node can only have one parent. This is often convenient to reuse to create the navigation on your site - but sometimes it isn't. In those cases, you need to use some other method to create the links to "master" from "products", "training", and "timetable".